# Variable in Header

Tags: php, redirect, header

```
$c = 'Hello.php';

header('Refresh: 2; URL= $c ');
```

This is not working. Is this legal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is legal but you will need to use "" as string delimiters

```
$c = 'Hello.php';

header("Refresh: 2; URL= $c ");
```

Also see: http://nl.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php on single and double quoted strings

Answer (score 4):

Variable interpolation only occurs in double quoted (`"`) strings.

```
$c = 'Hello.php';

header("Refresh: 2; URL= $c");
```

Comment: This is a very very valuable answer